# Правильная настройка ssl vhost apache2 gentoo

Tags: unix, apache2, ssl, gentoo

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно настроить *vhosts apache*. Есть три сайта в `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sites`

Все три работают исправно.

Когда на один из них купил SSL сертификата и подключил его с помощью редиректа с 80 на 443 порт начались проблемы, а именно:
Допустим сайты: `http://site1.com` `http://site2.com` `https://site3.com`
Если ручками вводишь `https://site1.com`, то браузер сообщает о не безопасном подключении и переходит на site3.com, но в адресной строке остается `https://site1.com`....

Код редиректа с 80 на 443 порт.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Код редиректа с 80 на 443 порт.

если вы его вставили глобально, вне какой-либо секции *virtualhost*, то, вероятно, это не то, что вам нужно: ведь теперь будут перенаправляться обращения ко **всем** сайтам.

если вам надо было перенаправить только один из сайтов, то надо было создать новый *virtualhost* с нужным содержимым:

```
<virtualhost *:443>
  servername site1.com
  ...
</virtualhost>
```

а старый привести, например, к такому виду:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  servername site1.com
  redirect permanent / https://site1.com
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: `<virtualhost *:80>
servername site1.com RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}</virtualhost>` вот так сейчас сделано